# Autocorrelation linear combination

Tags: mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation

Suppose I have an index $X_t$ over time, which is a linear combination of $N$ other time-series $x_{i,t}$. So $X_t= \sum_i^n w_{i}x_{i,t}$,. Is there a theoretical/statistical formula that decomposes the autocorrelation structure of the index in terms of the autocorrelation of the underlying time series and potentially the interaction among these time series; for example $x_{i,t-j}$ is correlated with $x_{z,t}$?

For variances this is clear, there we can decompose the variance of an index in terms of the variances of the underlying variables and their corresponding co-variances. I wonder how this works for autocorrelations. I was not able to find a similar question on this forum.

Comment: Does $w_{i,t}$ really depend on $t$ here? Did you try to compute the autocovariance the same way you would compute the variance of $X_t$?

Comment: We could make the weights time-varying, but let's suppose they are constant. I will edit my question to this case. And yes, but I'm unable to see the decomposition structure as in the variance case..

Comment: In vector form $X_t = \overline{w}^T  \overline{x}_t$ hence $X_{t-\tau} X_{t} = \overline{w}^T \overline{x}_{t-\tau}  \overline{w}^T  \overline{x}_t =  \overline{w}^T  \overline{x}_{t-\tau} \overline{x}_t^T \overline{w}$ where $E[\overline{x}_{t-\tau} \overline{x}_t^T]$ will be the $n\times n$ autocovariance-matrix.